Creating a channel with small youtubers giveout error
within the code snipped bellow i am simpely trying to return the channel_id strange think is with some youtube channels i dont get the error with with the smaller once i am
take for example the following channels
https://www.youtube.com/@Blazedrust {big channel so no issue}
https://www.youtube.com/@daveyswerkplaats {random guy issue}
even sam sullek gives me the same issue lol
def checkID(self, channel_url_or_name: str) -> str:
    try:
        print(channel_url_or_name)
        return Channel(channel_url_or_name).channel_id

log messages :
daveyswerkplaats
https://www.youtube.com/c/daveyswerkplaats
Exception in thread Thread-1 (checkingFeed):
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\keize\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\threading.py", line 1016, in _bootstrap_inner  
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\keize\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\threading.py", line 953, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "E:\projects\Moederjager_bot\cogs\youtube_checker.py", line 63, in checkingFeed
    hiddenId = self.getChannelId(youtube_channel_id)
  File "E:\projects\Moederjager_bot\cogs\youtube_checker.py", line 40, in getChannelId
    return self.checkID(channel_url_or_name)
  File "E:\projects\Moederjager_bot\cogs\youtube_checker.py", line 31, in checkID
    return Channel(channel_url_or_name).channel_id
  File "C:\Users\keize\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pytube\contrib\channel.py", line 
58, in channel_id
    print(self.initial_data['metadata']['channelMetadataRenderer']['externalId'])
  File "C:\Users\keize\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pytube\contrib\playlist.py", line 81, in initial_data
    self._initial_data = extract.initial_data(self.html)
  File "C:\Users\keize\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pytube\contrib\channel.py", line 
79, in html
    self._html = request.get(self.videos_url)
  File "C:\Users\keize\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pytube\request.py", line 53, in get
    response = _execute_request(url, headers=extra_headers, timeout=timeout)
  File "C:\Users\keize\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pytube\request.py", line 37, in _execute_request
    return urlopen(request, timeout=timeout)  # nosec
  File "C:\Users\keize\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\urllib\request.py", line 216, in urlopen       
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "C:\Users\keize\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\urllib\request.py", line 525, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "C:\Users\keize\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\urllib\request.py", line 634, in http_response 
    response = self.parent.error(
  File "C:\Users\keize\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\urllib\request.py", line 557, in error
    result = self._call_chain(*args)
  File "C:\Users\keize\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\urllib\request.py", line 496, in _call_chain   
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\keize\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\urllib\request.py", line 749, in http_error_302    return self.parent.open(new, timeout=req.timeout)
  File "C:\Users\keize\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\urllib\request.py", line 525, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "C:\Users\keize\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\urllib\request.py", line 634, in http_response 
    response = self.parent.error(
  File "C:\Users\keize\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\urllib\request.py", line 557, in error
    result = self._call_chain(*args)
  File "C:\Users\keize\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\urllib\request.py", line 496, in _call_chain   
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\keize\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\urllib\request.py", line 749, in http_error_302    return self.parent.open(new, timeout=req.timeout)
  File "C:\Users\keize\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\urllib\request.py", line 525, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "C:\Users\keize\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\urllib\request.py", line 634, in http_response 
    response = self.parent.error(
  File "C:\Users\keize\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\urllib\request.py", line 563, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "C:\Users\keize\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\urllib\request.py", line 496, in _call_chain   
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\keize\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\urllib\request.py", line 643, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 404: Not Found

I wanted to recieve the same channel id type return as i had for blazed rust
i didnt fix it but i used difrent set of code here:
def get_channel_id_from_url(url):
response = requests.get(url)
if response.status_code == 200:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
    meta_tag = soup.find('meta', itemprop='channelId')
    if meta_tag:
        return meta_tag['content']
    link_tags = soup.find_all('link', rel='canonical')
    for link in link_tags:
        if 'channel' in link['href']:
            channel_id_match = re.search(r'\/channel\/([^\/]+)', link['href'])
            if channel_id_match:
                return channel_id_match.group(1)
return None


Have you tried updating your pytube it might be out of date by running pip install --upgrade pytube . Add some error handling which could help you with figuring out the issue.
